# taglist works with gvim not with vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, taglist

I can use taglist with gvim (launched from xterm) but not in vim(opened in putty). I get the following error when I try using taglist from vim `Taglist: Failed to generate tags for /home/abbcd/abcd/XXXX.c
ctags: unrecognized option '--format=2'^@^ITry 'ctags --help' for a complete list of options.^@` 
Wondering why it works fine with gvim and not in vim.

Comment: Is it possible they're using distinct `ctags` binaries? Perhaps `$PATH` is set differently from PuTTY than on xterm? Try `which ctags` on the shell to verify that... Also try plain `vim` on xterm to see whether it works or if it also fails. Do you have a `.gvimrc` file?

Comment: @filbranden, it works well with vim on xterm . As you suggested I checked ```which ctags``` from both xterm and from PuTTY. It showed different ctags locations. How can I set the path of correct ctags in the vimrc/profile files. I dont want to change the PATH environment variable whole as I have other binary paths which may get affected. I just need only the ctags path to be set to correct in PuTTY terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, the difference is in how `$PATH` is being set depending on how you connect.

The `taglist.vim` plugin file has a comment that says:

> 3. If the exuberant ctags utility is not present in your PATH, then set the
>      `Tlist_Ctags_Cmd` variable to point to the location of the exuberant ctags utility (not to the directory) in the .vimrc file.

So add a line to your `.vimrc` file with something like:

```
let g:Tlist_Ctags_Cmd = '/usr/local/bin/ctags'
```

Use the path to the ctags binary that is working correctly for you. (The one returned by `which ctags` in the xterm.)